# Align Right LinearLayout to right and fill left LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml

I have a simple question.
I would like to do this in the attached image:

[image: descripted my problem]

How to se t my LinearLayout?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty easy.
You can fill remaining space using weightSum.
Check below code.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <LinearLayout           // This is First LinearLayout.
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5"/>

    <LinearLayout           // This is Remaining Space.
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>

    <LinearLayout           // This is Second LinearLayout what you want to put right.
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Remember that all sums of values of layout_weight should be same with weightSum.
Hoping it will be helped.